# Code Igniter authentication library

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I just learn new Code Igniter, look for login with register and authentication so I could get user group role like admin and member and other.

I would like to know what is the best Code Igniter authentication library which fits my requirements.

Anyone could help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Use Ion Auth. Use Codeigniter 3 (not 2). If you google there are tutorials for ion auth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ion Auth** is a simple and lightweight authentication library for the CodeIgniter framework.

**Documentation** is located at http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/

**Installation**

Just copy the files from this package to the corresponding folder in your application folder. For example, copy Ion_auth/config/ion_auth.php to application/config/ion_auth.php

You can also copy the entire directory structure into your third_party/ folder. For example, copy everything to /application/third_party/ion_auth/

**CodeIgniter Version 2 Compatibility**

CodeIgniter v2 requires the class file names to be lowercase. In order to support this follow the standard installation procedures and then either rename the following files or create symlinks

```
models/Ion_auth_model.php         =>   models/ion_auth_model.php
controllers/Auth.php              =>   controllers/auth.php
```

Hope that helps, cheers